# InvalidPipelineOperator MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$replaceAll'

Tags: mongodb

I am running following code in MongoDB:

```
db.response_graphs.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match : {
                "Response_measure" : "MasksMandatory"
            }
        },
        {
            $project : {
                date_end: { $replaceAll: { input: "$date_end", find: "NA", replacement: "2020-08-01" }}
            }
        }
        ]
    )
```

I am getting following error:

{
"message" : "Unrecognized expression '$replaceAll'",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
"name" : "MongoError"
}

I am following the syntax from the following link still getting the above error:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/

Please help me resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace all is new in 4.4 Your probably running an older version.